# Can't completely remove distro Regolith; alternative session is still available

Tags: 20.04, window-manager, i3-wm

I tried [Regolith](https://regolith-linux.org/) on my VM to play with i3. I liked this distro very much and wanted to install it on my main machine. I'm trying to remove it on my VM. I followed this [official uninstallation guide](https://regolith-linux.org/docs/getting-started/install/#uninstallation-of-regolith-desktop):

```
Log out of the Regolith session and into the default Ubuntu session.

$ sudo apt purge regolith-desktop && sudo apt autoremove

Now remove the PPA:

$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:regolith-linux/release

You can now safely delete the directory ~/.config/regolith.
```

But after logging out, I could still change session to `Regolith` and log in to it successfully. It's fully functional. How do I completely remove Regolith?

System info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64
DE: GNOME
WM: Mutter
```

Answer (score 0):

**It turns out that I had installed the standalone i3.** My guess is that Regolith somehow "attached" itself to the standalone i3, and that's why the official uninstallation process didn't work.

1. Follow the official uninstallation process:

```
Log out of the Regolith session and into the default Ubuntu session.


$ sudo apt purge regolith-desktop && sudo apt autoremove
```

2. Check any remaining left of Regolith:

```
apt list --installed | grep regolith
```

You should not see any remaining packages. If you see any, remove them with `sudo apt remove package-name`

3. Remove previously installed i3.

```
apt list --installed | grep i3
```

Again, remove them with `sudo apt remove package-name`

Log out and you should not see Regolith session available.

Comment: Using `ppa-purge ppa:regolith-linux/release` will be better.